# Vacation time when resigning with 2 weeks notice

Tags: vacation

I have some vacation time due which I'm about to take, and I've now received an offer for a better job.  My vacation time will occur during the standard 2 week notice period.

I'm worried that when I give my 2 weeks notice, my employer will take the paid vacation time from me. Will I still get my vacation pay if I resign now?

Comment: Hey Andria, and welcome to [workplace.se]! I'm a bit confused as to what your question is. Why do you think they will take it away? What do you want to do about it? As explained in our [help/dont-ask], *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."* As-is, your question may be put [on hold](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should also include the country you're in (add a tag). Although this website is not about legal issues, there may be laws/rules regarding this in your country.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to answer without knowing specifics of your workplace agreement or contract - but in my part of the world, accrued paid vacation time is refunded as basic salary if you resign. However, the company may be able to require you to take the equivalent days off during your notice period.

In you particular instance (now you've cleared up your question a bit more) - you should still be entitled to the annual leave you've accrued, and you've booked the time already. You might cause a bit of umbrage at leaving under these terms. You could offer three weeks notice, instead (assuming your vacation is one week) - giving two weeks work, still.

All of this does depend on what employment laws apply in your part of the world, and also what is specified in your contract - and has been mentioned in your contract, you should talk to HR about your situation.

Comment: I put my vacation time in over a month ago had it approved and last Thursday a job offer at a deferent company came along I'm worried that if I get the other job and put my 2 weeks in that will fall in the week of my vacation and that they will tell me that I have to work the two weeks I have left at the company and not get to have me paid week b4 I leave the company

Comment: @andria that comment should be in your question. It's very relevant to any answer that will help you.